# Horizontal overflow grid of 2 columns and 2 rows

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble trying to add a horizontal overflow to my grid.

[image]

I would like the last element of my grid to go to the right in a new column and the whole grid to overflow. The new column would be hidden but by scrolling to the right I could see it. Like on this image for example :

[image]

Here is my css code :

```css
.projects {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Anyone have any idea how I could do this ? Thank you alot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to a column flow and remove the column template:

```css
.projects {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: calc((100% - 1rem)/2); /* 2 columns visible */
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.projects div{
  border:2px solid;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects ">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help !!